# Reference dll 's are missing from the solution after going for new work space or branching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I created the MVC application and build the solution in my local machine and it builds without error then I have uploaded that MVC application into TFVC. But, if i take a new workspace from the other developer machine or going for the Branching feature in TFVC, we have been endup with all the reference dll's which was showing deleted like below screen shot and the solution does not build successfully. We are not sure what its causing the issue. Please help us to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Update**
Actual problem i am facing here is, I run **update-package -reinstall** command in the Package Manager Console, it removed all the existing dll's and restored back all the dll and build successfully. But, After successful Build, I have checked-in the pending changes into TFS. But again if I am taking the new workspace from another developer machine, i am still endup with the same build error and missing reference like above screen shot again i have to go for the Nuget Package Restore. Is it a Correct approach? Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: Do you update the nuget packages before building the solution ?

Comment: yes i updated and went for the update-package -reinstall command , it removed all the existing dll's and restored back all the dll and build successfully. but, i checked in the pending changes into TFS after the successful build but again if i am taking the new workspace from another developer machine, i am still endup with the same build error and missing reference like above screen shot. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: one day same thing happen with my code, found no solutions except add the reference again manually :(

Comment: Check the HintPath in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on the solution and select restore nuget package this may solve your issue then clean and build

check dot net framework version in both `tfs` and `local version`

you can also try

`update-package -reinstall` command to reinstall all referenced packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try restoring missing NuGet packages, check that the option is checked in VS Settings > NuGet.